# VBA: Check if value from first sheet column a exists in second shift column A. If yes, then copy whole row

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm new in VBA and actually don't know how to deal with that task. Maybe you can help me.

I have two tables in two sheets.
Table from sheet 1 is updated daily.

What I need to do is check if any value in column A (sheet 1) is in column A (sheet 2).
If yes, then do nothing.
If no, then copy whole row into the table in sheet 2.

Basing on google results I started to write some code but I stuck.

```
    Dim source            As Worksheet
    Dim finaltbl          As Worksheet
    Dim rngsource         As Range
    Dim rngfinaltbl       As Range


    'Set Workbook
    Set source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    Set finaltbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2")

    'Set Column
    Set rngsource = source.Columns("A")
    Set rngfinaltbl = finaltbl.Columns("A")
```

I assume that next I need to write some loop but I really don't know how it works.

Comment: Is there any local VBA language (a language other than US English) where the default first worksheet is named `Sheet 1` instead of `Sheet1`? Anyone?

Comment: Yes, there is local language. Sheet 1 -> "Pobrane dane" and Sheet 2 -> "Baza v2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update Worksheet With Missing (Unique) Rows (Dictionary)

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Sub UpdateData()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
        
    ' Reference the destination worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dName)
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim drCount As Long
    
    ' Reference the destination data range.
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
        Set dCell = .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If dCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in column range
        drCount = dCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set drg = .Resize(drCount)
    End With
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    
    ' Write the values from the destination range to an array.
    If drCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = drg.Value
    Else
        Data = drg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write the unique values from the array to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        Key = Data(dr, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude errors
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next dr
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    
    ' Reference the source data range.
    With sws.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        Set sCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in column range
        srCount = sCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
        
    ' Write the values from the source range to an array.
    If srCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else
        Data = srg.Value
    End If
        
    Dim surg As Range
    Dim sr As Long
    
    ' Loop through the source values...
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        Key = Data(sr, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude errors
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then ' if source value doesn't exist...
                    dict(Key) = Empty ' ... add it (to the dictionary)...
                    If surg Is Nothing Then ' and combine the cell into a range.
                        Set surg = srg.Cells(sr)
                    Else
                        Set surg = Union(surg, srg.Cells(sr))
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
        
    ' Copy all source rows in one go below ('.Offset(1)') the last cell.
    If Not surg Is Nothing Then
        surg.EntireRow.Copy dCell.Offset(1).EntireRow
    End If
    
    MsgBox "Data updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm impressed of the code which you wrote but unfortunately it does not work for me. I replaced Sheet 1 by destination sheet and sheet 2 by source then run the code and nothing is happened. Any ideas?

Comment: so my table in sheet 1 (destiny table) was empty. After I have added there first line then your code works without any problem :) Thanks a lot!!!!! Thank you for comments in the code as well!!!

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need a loop. You need the Find function for a Range
See [Documentation for Find Method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)
also [Excel VBA Find  A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/)